# .htaccess does not execute in subdirectories?

Tags: .htaccess, http, get

I am trying to achieve the following redirect:

`http://localhost/api/user/list?limit=10`
to
`http://localhost/api/index.php/user/list?limit=10`

My .htaccess file works fine according to https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/, but when I test it, I get a 404 Not Found error.

**What I have tried**

In my .htaccess file I included a rule that sets a header. This way, I can check with postman whether or not the rule has been executed.

When I send a GET request to `http://localhost/api`, I see my "TEST_FOOBAR" header in the response. However, when I send a GET request to `http://localhost/api/user`, the header is no longer there.

However, when I send a request to `http://localhost/api/inc` (an existing folder), I do get to see my header.

This makes me believe that my .htaccess only listens to and rewrites requests that are being sent to `http://localhost/api`, and not its **"virtual"** subfolders.

I've been googling for a while but can't seem to figure out why it's not rewriting calls to **"virtual"** subdirectories?

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api(.*)$ /api/index.php$1
Header set TEST_FOOBAR "oi"
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^api(.*)$ /api/index.php$1
> ```

By itself, this looks like it would result in a rewrite-loop, since the target URL `/api/index.php...` is also matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^api(.*)$`, so a request for `/api/user` would be rewritten as follows:

1. `/api/user` to `/api/index.php/user`
2. `/api/index.php/user` to `/api/index.php/index.php/user`

Try the following instead, to prevent the rewritten request being further rewritten:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^api(/.*)$ /api/index.php$1 [L]
```

There must always be a slash after `api` (for the substitution to be valid), so I've included this in the capturing group.

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var ensures that only the initial request is processed and not the rewritten request. I used this method, as opposed to explicitly checking for `/api/index.php` since it allows direct requests to `/api/index.php` to be handled by your API and processed accordingly (perhaps even rejecting the request).

> In my .htaccess file I included a rule that sets a header. This way, I can check with postman whether or not the rule has been executed.

This doesn't necessarily tell you whether the `RewriteRule` directive has been successfully processed or not. Different Apache modules are processed entirely independently, and at different times during the request. If the header is not set then it just means that the `Header` directive was not processed successfully (perhaps due to an error).

> When I send a GET request to `http://localhost/api`

Since `/api` is a physical subdirectory, if you request `/api` without a trailing slash then mod_dir should ultimately 301 redirect the request to `/api/` (appending the trailing slash). Your test header should not be set on the redirect response (since you are not using the `always` condition on the `Header` directive).

> My .htaccess file works fine according to `htaccess.madewithlove.com`

The MWL tester only simulates a single pass by the rewrite engine so cannot detect rewrite/redirect-loops. On a real server the rewrite engine loops until the URL passes through unchanged or encounters an `END` flag (Apache 2.4). (The `L` flag simply stops the current pass by the rewrite engine, triggering the rewrite engine to begin another pass.)

In the above rule you could use the `END` flag (instead of `L`) which would negate the need for the preceding *condition*.

Comment: Hello! Thanks a bunch for your help. I've replaced my .htaccess with your script, but I'm still receiving a 404 error.
I also tried to remove the condition and add the END flag instead of the L flag, but that didn't work either.